# How to check if two subspaces are conjugate?

Tags: matrix, logic, resolve

I want to check if there exists an element $g \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})^2$ such that $Ad(g) \mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{h}_\lambda$ for some given subalgebras $\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}_\lambda \subset \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})^2$.
More precisely:
$\mathfrak{h}_\lambda$ depends on a real parameter $\lambda$ and I want to know for which $\lambda$ the subalgebras are conjugate in the above sense.

I tried

```
Resolve[
Exists[
g,ForAll[
element1 in h,Exists[
element2 in hlambda,g.element1==element2.g
]],Reals]
```

(I used some shorthands here to avoid spelling out my implementations of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and the subalgebras)
My hope was to get some condition on $\lambda$ (something like $\lambda=\pm 1$), but Mathematica just prints the previous Exists/ForAll/Exists statement.

EDIT:
As my reputation is too low, I cannot reply to comments via own comments. In a comment, I was asked what my background about theorem provers is, and it was pointed out to me, that maybe Mathematica is not the right tool to solve my problem. I thought my problem was basically a linear algebra one, and Mathematica has proven to be very helpful for these problems in the past. I don't know anything about theorem provers, but I can believe that they're more helpful to solve my problem. Any suggestion for a particular software?

Comment: What is your background with theorem provers? I'm not sure why you want to do this in Mathematica. If you look at the documentation for Resolve, you should get a good feeling for it's scope.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `FindEquationalProof`?